# Reset JavaScript function that self-executes

Tags: jquery, function, loops, kill

I've got a simple function that loops itself. I'd like to kill kill it and then re-execute it based on user action. Not sure what the best way to do it is.

Here's what I've got:

```
function loopor(){

    $slider.next();

    setTimeout(loopor, 3000);
}
```

And here's what I need to do:

```
$('#thing').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var thing = $(this);

    /* help here */
    magicKillLooporFunction();
    /* end help*/

    thing.animate({
        height: '100%'
    }, function({
        loopor();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myTimeout;
function loopor(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);  //Add this so multiple clicks don't create multiple timeouts
    $slider.next();
    myTimeout = setTimeout(loopor, 3000);
}
```

And then in the other code

```
$('#thing').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var thing = $(this);
    clearTimeout(mytimeout);
    thing.animate({
    height: '100%'
    }, function({
        loopor();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest solution:

```
(function($) {
     var $slider, //Assign value
         timeout;
     function loopor() {
          $slider.next();
          timeout = setTimeout(loopor, 3000);
     }
     $('#thing').click(function(event){

          event.preventDefault();

          var thing = $(this);

          /* help here */
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          /* end help*/

          thing.animate({
              height: '100%'
          }, function({
              loopor();
          });
     });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is a better more complete solution than mine, except you'll need to also add a clear timeout in the looper so that the variable `timeout` doesn't get overwritten if a click happens while animate is in process.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean:

```
if(keeprunning) setTimeout(loopor, 3000);
```